# base 64 image undefined error when trying to perform get request with angular UI

Tags: angular, image, get, base64, undefined

I have a simple UI where when a user enters a name and presses a button, a get request is sent and I would like the image from that get request to be rendered in the browser. However, that image is not being rendered. Below is my UI:
[image: ui]

When the button is pressed, the following error appears in the console:

```
GET data:image/jpeg;base64,undefined net::ERR_INVALID_URL
```

Below is my component file:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  data:any
  image:any
  retrievedImage: any;
  base64Data: any;
  retrieveResonse: any;
  imageName:any;

  constructor(private imageData:imageService,
              private httpClient:HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {

    console.log(this.image)
   

    this.imageData.getImages().subscribe((results)=>{
     console.log(results)
     this.data = results
     })
  }

  getImage2() {
    //Make a call to Sprinf Boot to get the Image Bytes.
    this.httpClient.get('http://localhost:8080/get/' + this.imageName,
      {responseType:'blob'})
      .subscribe(
        res => {
          this.retrieveResonse = res;
          this.base64Data = this.retrieveResonse.picByte;
          this.retrievedImage = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + this.base64Data;
        }
      );
  }
}
```

Below is my HTML file:

```html
<p>
    <mat-toolbar>
      <span>Image Repository</span>
    </mat-toolbar>
  </p>
<button mat-button style="position:relative; left: 5px; top:2px" (click)="getImage2()">Get an image </button>
<input #image type="text" style="position:relative;left:10px; top: 2.99px" [(ngModel)]="imageName">


<!-- <img *ngIf="image" style="position:relative;top:200px" [src]="image" alt="Place image title"> 
 -->
<div class="container row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
      <div *ngIf=retrievedImage>
          <img [src]="retrievedImage" style="position:relative;top:200px" src="data:image/png;base64,{{image}}">
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How would I go about fixing this error? I'm not sure why the image would be undefined.

Edit: It looks like the this.base64data variable is showing up as undefined but I am not sure why

Comment: did you receive the response from the API? I guess `retrieveResonse.picByte` is undefined

Comment: @YashRami yes that variable is undefined actually. Im not sure why though, I use the same url in postman and I get a response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the response is just the bytes. In this case, I believe you can use the endpoint URL right in the `img.src`.

```js
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  imageUrl: string;

  getImage2() {
    //Update the image url
    this.imageUrl= 'http://localhost:8080/get/' + this.imageName;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
      <div *ngIf=retrievedImage>
          <img [src]="imageUrl" style="position:relative;top:200px" src="data:image/png;base64,{{image}}">
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ah yes, I got rid of the second src binding however I still get the same error

Comment: I would guess that image bytes are stored in the different property, not in the `this.retrieveResonse.picByte`. Maybe there is a typo in the `picByte` for example.

Comment: @ IAfanasov Yes it looks like the bytes are not stored there but there is no typo that i see in picByte so im not quite sure why its undefined

Comment: is it possible to share a response? maybe as a text file or as a gist

Comment: ah you mean the response from the API? The response is just an image so im not quite sure how I would share it

Comment: image doesn't have an `picByte` property (:

Comment: I updated the answer to follow the last comment